# How do I add constraints to my tabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have added a `tabBarController` and hooked it up to `viewControllers` and given the `tabBarController` its own `class`. It works, but I would like to customize it by changing the `constraints` so that it's not right at the bottom. From what I can see there's no way to add `constraints` in `auto layout` as it's all grayed out. I gave a shot at adding it programmatically, but nothing happens.

```
final class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    @IBOutlet var customTabBar: UITabBar!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.selectedIndex = 2
        let fontAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)]

        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(fontAttributes, for: .normal)

        //This doesn't work
        customTabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        //Neither does this
        self.tabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        //Or this
        if let tabC = self.tabBarController {
            tabC.tabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }
```

So how do I do this? I want the `tabBar` to be about 50p from the bottom.

Comment: So what is your rootViewController? TabBarController? In that case I don't think you can change the tab bar frame, you should rather use simple view controller add tab bar at the bottom and basically implement the functionality of tab bar controller on your own

Comment: I set the storyboard's tabBarController's class to TabBarController, so I would say yes. Ok, so just a tabBar then? Thanks!

Comment: It's possible to move the tab bar but it's hacky, and will cause unintended side effects. *Do not* reimplement the functionality of the tab bar yourself, @Craz1k0ek has posted the correct answer. I was writing out the same answer when I noticed he'd already provided it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a container view controller to hold you `UITabBarController`.
Then, when you set the constraints on your container view, you can add 'padding' to the bottom, to have it go upwards. Below are two screenshots explaining the layout.

[image]
[image]